# problemas com conversão de data com php

Tags: php, data, timestamp

Tenho a seguinte função que transforma timestamp em data legível em português

```
function dataEmPortugues ($timestamp, $hours = TRUE, $timeZone = "America/Sao_Paulo") {
  $timestamp=strtotime($timestamp);
    $dia_num = date("w", $timestamp);// Dia da semana.

    if($dia_num == 0){
      $dia_nome = "Domingo";
    }elseif($dia_num == 1){
      $dia_nome = "Segunda-feira";
    }elseif($dia_num == 2){
      $dia_nome = "Terça-feira";
    }elseif($dia_num == 3){
      $dia_nome = "Quarta-feira";
    }elseif($dia_num == 4){
      $dia_nome = "Quinta-feira";
    }elseif($dia_num == 5){
      $dia_nome = "Sexta-feira";
    }else{
      $dia_nome = "Sábado";
    }

    $dia_mes = date("d", $timestamp);// Dia do mês

    $mes_num = date("m", $timestamp);// Nome do mês

    if($mes_num == 01){
      $mes_nome = "Janeiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 02){
      $mes_nome = "Fevereiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 03){
      $mes_nome = "Março";
    }elseif($mes_num == 04){
      $mes_nome = "Abril";
    }elseif($mes_num == 05){
      $mes_nome = "Maio";
    }elseif($mes_num == 06){
      $mes_nome = "Junho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 07){
      $mes_nome = "Julho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 08){
      $mes_nome = "Agosto";
    }elseif($mes_num == 09){
      $mes_nome = "Setembro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 10){
      $mes_nome = "Outubro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 11){
      $mes_nome = "Novembro";
    }else{
      $mes_nome = "Dezembro";
    }
    $ano = date("Y", $timestamp);// Ano

    date_default_timezone_set($timeZone); // Set time-zone
    $hora = date ("H:i", $timestamp);

    if ($hours) {
      return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano." às ".$hora;
    }
    else {
      return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano;
    }
  }
```

tenho um time stamp

```
2016-11-30 15:12:09
```

e quando converto usando esta função ele retorna

```
Quarta-feira, 30 de Novembro de 2016 às 13:12
```

esta retornando com 2 horas de diferença. como arrumo isso ?

Comment: experimente com gmdate e veja o que acontece

Comment: mesmas 2 horas d diferença

Comment: na verdade é simples, precisa por o `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` logo que abre o `<?php`, pq seu timestamp está vindo de fora. Se tiver um include de conexao de DB, e/ou alguma config usada em geral, pode aproveitar e já deixar lá. Remova isso da função, pq nao vai adiantar nada mudar dentro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade de dar uma "ajeitada" no padrão de código e remover redundâncias. Mas mantive a estrutura para não ser muito invasivo.

Um ponto interessante é que a partir do PHP7 o trecho com `} elseif ($mes_num == 08) {` poderia causar o erro tipo "parse" `Invalid numeric literal`.

> Antes, octais literais que continham números inválidos, eram
>   silenciosamente truncados (0128 se tornaria 012). Agora, um octal
>   literal inválido causará um erro de parse.
>   Consulte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.integers

Por isso removi todos os zeros a esquerda, mas de qualquer forma independente disso eu já teria removido.

Isso é apenas uma observação pois não era isso que causava o erro relatado na pergunta e desvia um pouco do foco principal.

Sobre o motivo do código original apresentar horário com 2 horas de diferença, não averiguei. Apenas refiz o script para um jeito mais fácil extraindo os valores com a função `substr()` pois julguei desnecessário fazer tantas chamadas a função `date()`, `timezone`, etc.

O importante é que a mudança faz com que função retorne o que deseja.

```
function dataEmPortugues($date, $hours = true)
{

    $dia_num = date('w', strtotime($date));// Dia da semana.

    if($dia_num == 0) {
        $dia_nome = 'Domingo';
    } elseif ($dia_num == 1) {
        $dia_nome = 'Segunda-feira';
    } elseif ($dia_num == 2) {
        $dia_nome = 'Terça-feira';
    } elseif ($dia_num == 3) {
        $dia_nome = 'Quarta-feira';
    } elseif ($dia_num == 4) {
        $dia_nome = 'Quinta-feira';
    } elseif ($dia_num == 5) {
        $dia_nome = 'Sexta-feira';
    } else {
        $dia_nome = 'Sábado';
    }

    // Faz um cast integer para remover zeros a esquerda
    $mes_num = (int)substr($date, 5, 2);// Nome do mês

    if($mes_num == 1) {
        $mes_nome = 'Janeiro';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 2) {
        $mes_nome = 'Fevereiro';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 3) {
        $mes_nome = 'Março';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 4) {
        $mes_nome = 'Abril';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 5) {
        $mes_nome = 'Maio';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 6) {
        $mes_nome = 'Junho';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 7) {
        $mes_nome = 'Julho';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 8) {
        $mes_nome = 'Agosto';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 9) {
        $mes_nome = 'Setembro';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 10) {
        $mes_nome = 'Outubro';
    } elseif ($mes_num == 11) {
        $mes_nome = 'Novembro';
    } else {
        $mes_nome = 'Dezembro';
    }

    return $dia_nome.', '.(int)substr($date, 8, 2).' de '.$mes_nome.' de '.substr($date, 0, 4).($hours? ' às '.substr($date, 11, 5): '');
}

echo dataEmPortugues('2016-11-30 15:12:09');
```

Tempo de execução: 0.0000169277191162109s (0.0169 milisegundos)

Answer (score 2):

### Repensando no código:

No caso de usar a versão runtime, `date_default_timezone_set`, chame-a ANTES de usar as funções de data. No começo do código que chama a função, e não dentro dela.

No seu código aparentemente você está usando no meio da função, sendo que para ter consistência, teria que usar uma vez só logo depois de abrir o PHP.

### Alternativas de configuração:

Quem define o fuso horário do PHP é essa função:

```
bool date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

Ou esta diretiva da configuração:

```
date.timezone =
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
>   
>   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

**Nota:** se em alguma situação precisar do horário sem o fuso, pode optar pela função `gmdate()`, que usa os mesmos parâmetros, mas toma a UTC como base.

### Escolhendo a *string* correta:

Abaixo, os links do manual para facilitar para quem for customizar as chamadas para uma região específica.

Para Brasil, pode usar:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

E para Portugal:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
```

Veja a lista completa aqui:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php

Comment: sim ja estou usando essa função veja no meu script temo default timezone dentro dela

Comment: @JasarOrion experimente mudar para o local indicado na atualização

Comment: fiz como vc solicitou e ainda continua com 2 horas de diferença. Sera que meu apache esta errado ou meu php ou ate o Mysql?

Comment: Estranho. Vc tem acesso ao php.ini? precisa ver como está lá. E ver se as timezones estao ok no PHP, uma olhada no log do apache pode ajudar. Mesmo assim vou reler tudo e ver se consigo pensar em mais possibilidades.

Comment: @JasarOrion na verdade é simples, precisa por o `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` logo que abre o `<?php`, pq seu timestamp está vindo de fora. Se tiver um include de DB, e classe, pode aproveitar e já deixar lá. Remova isso da função, pq nao vai adiantar nada mudar dentro.

Comment: tendi , eu fiz um date no php e retorna ate os segundos exatos somenet quando pego o timestamp do db e tento converter que fica 2 horas defasado

Comment: Vai ver que no DB foi gravado defasado. O campo do DB é `date` ou é `timestamp`? Se estiver tudo defasado, com um update já arruma geral. Precisa ver se não faltou o date_default_timezone no arquivo que grava no DB.